# Apache2 started without LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, apache

On Suse11, I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my user env. Then I start apache2 by 
apache2ctl start

But I find LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not inherited by apache2 process.
Is there any flag I need to specify?

Comment: `/etc/apache2/envvars` seems to be relevant (see `man apache2ctl`).

Comment: By starting the process that way indeed your personal environment variables do not get passed down. That would work if you would directly start the executable, but not by using the daemon control, since that changes the user account and does a clean start. My primary question is: why would you want to change that PATH variable? Do you have some exotic setup for the http server? What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I forget to mention one thing, I use sudo to start http server. I need LD_LIBRARY_PATH because of an external PHP module depends on some libs to start up. And I find that the 'sudo' command eliminated my LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
   Note that the dynamic linker on most operating systems will remove variables that can control dynamic linking from the environment of setuid executables,
   including sudo.  Depending on the operating system this may include _RLD*, DYLD_*, LD_*, LDR_*, LIBPATH, SHLIB_PATH, and others.  These type of variables are
   removed from the environment before sudo even begins execution and, as such, it is not possible for sudo to preserve them.
```

Finally I start http server with "sudo -E LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH apache2ctl start" to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.